# How to add tabs in tabview in primefaces, dynamically, on click of a command button?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**How do I add tabs in `tabview` in `primefaces`, dynamically, on click of a command button using ajax?**

```
     <p:tabView id="tabview" dynamic="true" cache="false" 
    binding="#{TestBean.tabView}" 
    activeIndex="0" 
    scrollable="true">

        <p:tab title="tab1" closable="true">
            <h:outputLabel value="1"></h:outputLabel>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="tab2" closable="true">
            <h:outputLabel value="2"></h:outputLabel>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="tab3" closable="true">
            <h:outputLabel value="3"></h:outputLabel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

backing bean is

```
public class TestBean {

    TabView tabView;
    int id=0;



    public TestBean() {
    }

    public String addTab() {

        String tabId="tab"+id;
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setTitle("Title: "+tabId);
       tab.setId(tabId);

        tabView.getChildren().add(id,tab);

        id++;
        return "tabtest.jsf";
    }

    public TabView getTabView() {
        return tabView;
    }


    public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
        this.tabView = tabView;
    }
```

This is my backing bean. I am new to `jsf` and `Primefaces`. Kindly help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `addTab()` , you can add,

```
TabView tabView = new TabView();
Tab newTab = new Tab();            
newTab.setTitle("Tab Title");       
tabView.getChildren().add(newTab);
```

And you should update the view to reflect the new tab. Use `RequestContext` for ajax update.

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
  context.update("tabview");
```