# show and hide primefaces tab via ajax

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have following water down version of primefaces tab view.

```
<p:tabview>
    <p:tab id="1">
        <p:selectOneMneu value="#{bean.answer}>
            <f:selectItem itemValue="yes"/>
            <f:selectItem itemValue="no" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="2" rendered=#{bean.answer eq 'yes'} >
        <h:outputText="answer is Yes."/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="3" rendered=#{bean.answer eq 'no'} >
        <h:outputText="answer is No."/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

There is a managed bean which captures the selected value of either "yes" or "no". When the value is evaluated, depends on the answer, one of the tabs will be hidden. Once you are satisfied with the choice made, he/she clicks a submit button to post the data.

My question is what if a user changes his/her mind before pressing a submit button. Go back to drop down menu (selectOneMenu) then changes the value from "yes" to "no". Then I am hoping dynamically the bean would retrieve updated answer without refreshing entire xhtml page. It seems like ajax is the answer but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: based on what I researched, I plan to add <p:ajax event="change" update="2,3" listener=".."/> within <p:tab id="1"..>. I wonder if I am going to a right direction. i will deploy it to app server and see what happens.

Comment: Won't work, tab does not have a renderer. You cannot update it. And if you could, hiding it by not rendering it, would never make you succeed in unhiding it this way. The only option I see is to use javascript to manipulate visibility via css

Comment: You can add or remove tabs dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293708/how-to-add-tabs-in-tabview-in-primefaces-dynamically-on-click-of-a-command-but

Comment: @sunofkyuss: Thank you for your reply. Although I don't intend to add/remove tab. The link you provided me could be an option. show/hide tab is working fine. I just want to go one step further in case a user changes his mind the choice he selected. I want dynamically reflect the tab based on new answer.

Comment: You are right, the link was a bit irrevelant. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it works for me. I hope this is what you need. Now you don't have to refresh the page but you have to update the form. I don't know why but updating tabView doesnt effect anything.

```
<h:form>

    <p:tabView>

        <p:tab title="select">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.answer}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="none" itemLabel="select" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel="yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel="no" />
                <f:ajax event="change" render="@form"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="yes" rendered="#{bean.answer.equals('yes')}">
            <h:outputText value="answer is Yes." />
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="no" rendered="#{bean.answer.equals('no')}">
            <h:outputText value="answer is No." />
        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

</h:form>
```

Comment: This works in the sence that it fully updates all tabs, including the full (maybe very complex form in the first tab).  If that is acceptable for OP, this is a good answer (I assumed that was not the case, since the answer you give would otherwise be to obvious, at least for me). If the two other tabs are simple, using javascript to hide/unhide is easier (assuming that doesnot introduce a security issue)

Comment: @sunofkyuss: Yes, that is it! I have to wrap it with <h:form> tag. I knew something simple was missing...However real <p:tabView> is complex. Original developer didn't include form tag for some reason. I will just play it with more. Hope introducing form tag wouldn't affect other tabs adversely...